# How can I access an Express app.locals variable from within a client-side Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm very new to web development, and I'm working on a simple web app for educational purposes. I'm using Express, mongoDB and EJS.

I've got a route set up that correctly renders an ejs file, and from within that file, I have access to a value called `currentUser`. I've set up res.locals so that `currentUser` is available, and I've double-checked that by rendering it as text at the top of the page.

The issue is that I've got a `<script src="...">` that is handling some logic, and that's getting linked at the bottom of the `new.ejs` file. I'm trying to access app.locals.currentUser from within that script, but the console is giving me an uncaught reference error. The rest of the script is running as expected, but I just figure out how to access `currentUser` from within it.

I'm sure that this is a terribly simple problem, and I feel bad that I can't find what must be an obvious answer. I'm asking here because I've been searching for a few hours and I can't seem to structure the search query in a way that gives me an answer I can understand. How can I get that object into my script?

Edit: Adding some snippets for clarity:
In `new.ejs`, I have:

```
<div class="container">
   <h1 class="text-center"> Create new Request for <em><strong><%= currentUser.username %></strong></em> </h1>
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
...
<script src="/javascripts/search.js"></script>
```

At the top, username shows up just fine. However, in my `search.js`, I'm trying to call

```
console.log("Username is: " + currentUser);
```

Which is, of course, not working. It's clear that I'm going about trying access currentUser in the wrong way, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You should share the snippet that is trying to access `currentUser`

Comment: The `currentUser` is a server side variable. If you want to share the value to the client and perform some conditional rendering at the client side, be aware that this smells like potential vulnerability. It's safer to render this conditional at the server and send only the result to the client.

Comment: @MattD.Webb I went ahead and added some snippets, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @WiktorZychla That's exactly the kind of info I'm looking for! Would you be able to provide any info on how to go about doing that?

Comment: If you want us help you with processing `currentUser` at the server, please paste your `search.js` (just a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: You can also stay at client side and get HTMLElement containing `currentUser` using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: @macborowy Hey there, the only thing in the search.js at the moment is the console.log that I included in the question. Isn't that a minimal reproducible example? All I'm trying to do is access the variable, I can implement the rest of the search once I'm able to do that.

Comment: Can user change value he is searching for or is this always `currentUser.username`? How search form look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone finds themselves here, what I was looking for was the following:

```
<script src="/javascripts/search.js" currentUserId=<%= currentUser._id %> currentUserName=<%= currentUser.username %>></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this [library](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html) to set a cookie:

Comment: Neither of those options will work because the data is server-side and they both use client-side code.

Comment: So you can't create a cookie in a server? I'm sure there's the Express code to do it...

Comment: You can... but not the way you demonstrated in your answer.

Comment: for example by using cookie-parser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser